# Xcode Scene Editor Memory Leak Crashing Computer

Tags: xcode, macos, sprite-kit

I am having the same issue as seen here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/38432 Basically if the scene editor is open for a few minutes, my computer reboots with that memory leak error. Nobody seems to have come up with a solution there, so I am curious if anyone here has a solution. I have also reported this bug to Apple. Here is the crash log:

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8026b1f634): "zalloc: zone map exhausted while allocating from zone kalloc.8192, likely due to memory leak in zone kalloc.8192 (1123926016 total bytes, 137198 elements allocated)"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.60.10/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:2628
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff90c53e38a0 : 0xffffff8026adab52 
0xffffff90c53e3920 : 0xffffff8026b1f634 
0xffffff90c53e3a50 : 0xffffff8027039a9b 
0xffffff90c53e3a70 : 0xffffff7fa929f8d3 
0xffffff90c53e3a90 : 0xffffff7fa92233fc 
0xffffff90c53e3ac0 : 0xffffff7fa920ef71 
0xffffff90c53e3b40 : 0xffffff7fa9214228 
0xffffff90c53e3ba0 : 0xffffff7fa9215268 
0xffffff90c53e3be0 : 0xffffff80270dfed7 
0xffffff90c53e3d20 : 0xffffff8026b97f90 
0xffffff90c53e3e30 : 0xffffff8026adf2c3 
0xffffff90c53e3e60 : 0xffffff8026ac28f8 
0xffffff90c53e3ea0 : 0xffffff8026ad26a5 
0xffffff90c53e3f10 : 0xffffff8026bb8eca 
0xffffff90c53e3fb0 : 0xffffff8026becd86 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(205.11)[AE224148-CFD1-3A17-943F-E42B98EB06DC]@0xffffff7fa91ff000->0xffffff7fa926afff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[F51AA3D6-EC2F-3AD3-A043-06DB79027AA2]@0xffffff7fa7401000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[A360453D-2050-3C49-A549-AC0DD5E87917]@0xffffff7fa7f9c000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics(10.1.4)[6EBBF243-AAF9-3765-8E08-50CA36DA5F27]@0xffffff7fa9279000->0xffffff7fa92e1fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(108.2.3)[354FC780-7EA4-3C3F-A9E1-2658F63663A9]@0xffffff7fa7e20000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[F51AA3D6-EC2F-3AD3-A043-06DB79027AA2]@0xffffff7fa7401000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[A360453D-2050-3C49-A549-AC0DD5E87917]@0xffffff7fa7f9c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(205.11)[AE224148-CFD1-3A17-943F-E42B98EB06DC]@0xffffff7fa91ff000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Xcode

Mac OS version:
15G31

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 23 18:25:34 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: B5AA8E3E-65B6-3D0E-867B-8DCCF81E536C
Kernel slide:     0x0000000026800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8026a00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8026900000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 2566458908068
Zone Name              Cur Size  Free Size
vm objects             49098720       1920
vm object hash entri    7436000       2640
VM map entries         13414400       5200
pv_list                26222592       4992
vm pages               64320704      13568
kalloc.16               9301824       1120
kalloc.32               1290240     400192
kalloc.48              21938112        912
kalloc.64              21740544       3776
kalloc.96               1871328     649824
kalloc.128             71966720        896
kalloc.160              3003200       1760
kalloc.256            108310528        768
kalloc.512             12038144     465408
kalloc.1024             3780608       4096
kalloc.2048             3350528       2048
kalloc.4096             3428352          0
kalloc.8192          1123926016          0
mem_obj_control         2975616       2272
ipc ports              24267840       4480
threads                 1345536     381936
vnodes                 15977280       2880
namecache               6813600       4128
HFS node               21840864     231896
HFS fork                6062080      31360
ubc_info zone           4165656      49544
vnode pager structur    1892000      21040
compressor_pager        8896512         64
compressor_segment      7856128       1024
Kernel Stacks           2752512
PageTables            108298240
Kalloc.Large           47181331

Backtrace suspected of leaking: (outstanding bytes: 696320)
0xffffff8026b1fa6f 
0xffffff8027039a9b 
0xffffff7fa929f8d3 
0xffffff7fa92233fc 
0xffffff7fa920ef71 
0xffffff7fa9214228 
0xffffff7fa9215268 
0xffffff80270dfed7 
0xffffff8026b97f90 
0xffffff8026adf2c3 
0xffffff8026ac28f8 
0xffffff8026ad26a5 
0xffffff8026bb8eca 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(205.11)[AE224148-CFD1-3A17-943F-E42B98EB06DC]@0xffffff7fa91ff000->0xffffff7fa926afff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[F51AA3D6-EC2F-3AD3-A043-06DB79027AA2]@0xffffff7fa7401000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[A360453D-2050-3C49-A549-AC0DD5E87917]@0xffffff7fa7f9c000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics(10.1.4)[6EBBF243-AAF9-3765-8E08-50CA36DA5F27]@0xffffff7fa9279000->0xffffff7fa92e1fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(108.2.3)[354FC780-7EA4-3C3F-A9E1-2658F63663A9]@0xffffff7fa7e20000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[F51AA3D6-EC2F-3AD3-A043-06DB79027AA2]@0xffffff7fa7401000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[A360453D-2050-3C49-A549-AC0DD5E87917]@0xffffff7fa7f9c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(205.11)[AE224148-CFD1-3A17-943F-E42B98EB06DC]@0xffffff7fa91ff000

last loaded kext at 1251941963265: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs  3.0.1 (addr 0xffffff7fa97c9000, size 409600)
last unloaded kext at 653540897476: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7fa7ced000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
com.techsmith.TACC  1.0.2
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    2
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.1
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.22.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   274.12
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.6f1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   274.12
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1040.1.1a6
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.4
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.2.3
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.6f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.6f1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.11
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.8
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.50.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.4
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B0D, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638424455302D474E2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638424455302D474E2D4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.6f1 17910, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS545050A7E362, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS41N
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported the bug to Apple and they seem to have fixed the bug.